# convert class base component in react into hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm new to react hooks, and I'm having a hard time to convert this class,
into react hooks with ES6 syntax. could somone please help me.  here is my coude...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import { fetchMovie, setLoading } from '../../actions/searchActions';

import Spinner from '../layout/Spinner';

export class Movie extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchMovie(this.props.match.params.id);
    this.props.setLoading();
  }
  render() {
    const { loading, movie } = this.props;

    let movieInfo = (
      <div className="container">
       jsx......
 </div>
    );

    let content = loading ? <Spinner /> : movieInfo;
    return <div>{content}</div>;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  loading: state.movies.loading,
  movie: state.movies.movie
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { fetchMovie, setLoading }
)(Movie);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the most commonly used hooks are `useState`, `useEffect`. useState is similar to setState in certain ways, with one of the differences being that you don't have the callback functionality with useState. You could use a useEffect to achieve something similar. `useEffect` can work as `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate` and `componentWillUnmount`. If you pass an empty set of dependancies, `[]`(like in the following example), it behaves as `componentDidMount`. If you want a particular functionality to be triggered based on certain conditions such as a state being updated etc, you can pass that as a `dependancy`. Then, the `useEffect` behaves as `componentDidUpdate`. `useEffect` accepts a third argument, as a callback function. This is triggered when the component is being unmounted, thereby adding the `componentWillUnmount` behaviour.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import { fetchMovie, setLoading } from '../../actions/searchActions';

import Spinner from '../layout/Spinner';

const Movie = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    props.fetchMovie(props.match.params.id);
    props.setLoading();
  }, [])
  const { loading, movie } = props;

    let movieInfo = (
      <div className="container">
       jsx......
      </div>
    );

  let content = loading ? <Spinner /> : movieInfo;
  return <div>{content}</div>;
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  loading: state.movies.loading,
  movie: state.movies.movie
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { fetchMovie, setLoading }
)(Movie);
```

Comment: You forgot to remove the `this.props` and to pass props as the parameter.

Comment: @RodrigoAmaral: Every time :/

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite to hooks like that.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import { fetchMovie, setLoading } from '../../actions/searchActions';

import Spinner from '../layout/Spinner';

export const Movie = ({ match}) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const movie = useSelector(state => state.movies.movie);
  const loading = useSelector(state => state.movies.loading);
  useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchMovie(match.params.id));
        dispatch(setLoading());
     }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {
        loading 
         ? <Spinner /> 
         : <div className="container">
            jsx......
          </div>
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

useEffect with empty array as params works like componentDidMount. And i changed connect to useSelector and useDispatch